# SQL query avg function not working

Tags: oracle, group-by

This query produces the correct data :

```
select 
       extract (hour from (tr.eventts-pr.eventts))*3600+
       extract (minute from (tr.eventts-pr.eventts))*60+
       extract (second from(tr.eventts-pr.eventts))*1000 ms
,pr.pid
from (      select max((FROM_TZ(CAST(eventts AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific')) eventts, pid
            from WC_PACKAGEREPORT
            where DESTINATION=154
             AND PID in(SELECT unique pid FROM WC_PACKAGEINFO 
                        WHERE EXECUTEDTASK='ManualScan'  
                        and (FROM_TZ(CAST(eventts AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific') >= (FROM_TZ(CAST(trunc(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific')
          )
group by pid) pr

            inner join (  

select max((FROM_TZ(CAST(eventts AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific')) eventts, pid
from WC_TRACKINGREPORT
where areaid=1444
and zoneid=68
and equipmentid=03
group by pid) tr 

on tr.pid=pr.pid;
```

I now want to get the average ms taken so i try :

```
select 
       avg(extract (hour from (tr.eventts-pr.eventts))*3600+
       extract (minute from (tr.eventts-pr.eventts))*60+
       extract (second from(tr.eventts-pr.eventts))*1000) ms
,pr.pid
from (      select max((FROM_TZ(CAST(eventts AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific')) eventts, pid
            from WC_PACKAGEREPORT
            where DESTINATION=154
             AND PID in(SELECT unique pid FROM WC_PACKAGEINFO 
                        WHERE EXECUTEDTASK='ManualScan'  
                        and (FROM_TZ(CAST(eventts AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific') >= (FROM_TZ(CAST(trunc(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific')
          )
group by pid) pr

            inner join (  

select max((FROM_TZ(CAST(eventts AS TIMESTAMP),'+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific')) eventts, pid
from WC_TRACKINGREPORT
where areaid=1444
and zoneid=68
and equipmentid=03
group by pid) tr 

on tr.pid=pr.pid;
```

but i get a "not a single-group group function".

I believe I need to wrap the sql somewhere but I'm not sure where. Can any of you advise?

Tom

Comment: In your outermost  `select` any column that is not an aggregate function must be also in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 2):

At the outermost level, you are returning the average values along with `pr.pid`. If you want averages *per* `pid`, then you need to group your rows by `pid`.

You are doing that in the nested queries but not in the main one. So, after `on tr.pid=pr.pid` just add `group by pr.pid`.

But if you want the average value across the entire row set, remove `pr.pid` from the (main) select list.